# How do I add a play button on top of Bootstrap's carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using Bootstrap's carousel to do a slideshow in order to preview some of my videos.
I want to add a play button on top of the slideshow with a opacity change on hover.  (The button would not be clickable because the `href` is on the slideshow picture.  It's just here to show my user that it's a player.)

But I can't get my div to show the button on top of everything.  Here is my code:

```
<div class="carousel slide">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active"><a href="popup_video1.htm"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" /></a></div>
      <div class="item"><a href="popup_video2.htm"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" /></a></div>
      <div class="item"><a href="popup_video3.htm"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" /></a></div>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control left" href=".carousel" data-slide="prev">&nbsp;</a>
   <a class="carousel-control right" href=".carousel" data-slide="next">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS (it's using less but you get the idea):

```
.carousel {
width: 292px;
height: 163px;

  .playBtn {
    width: 292px;
    height: 163px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-image: url('play_btn.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 999;

      &:hover{
        opacity: 1;
      }
  }

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  a.carousel-control {
    margin-top: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 163px;

    &:hover.right {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: url('right_arrow.png');
    }

    &:hover.left {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: url('left_arrow.png');
    }
  }
}
```

(Note that my play button is not a play/pause for the slideshow.)

Where do I put my `<div class"playBtn"></div>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position: absolute`, just like the carousel controls, and place the play button similarly in the markup.  You shouldn't need to mess with `z-index` (besides if you were really in conflict with other Bootstrap elements with z-indices, they *start* at 1000).

If you want the play button's opacity to change based on it's own `:hover`, then you're going to have to deal with passing other mouse events it generates (i.e., clicks) onto the relevant elements.  Otherwise, if you want it's opacity to change based on another element's `mouseenter` event (e.g., hovering anywhere on the slide), you could give the play button `pointer-events:none`, and toggle a class in the event handler.